# Erro de sintaxe em "else if"

Tags: javascript

Com essa função o meu programa funciona, mas quando adiciono outra condição da erro:

```
if ((nota >= 6) && (frequencia >= 75)){
   alert("Aprovado");
}
else if (frequencia >= 50){
   alert("Recuperação");
}
else{
   alert("Reprovado");
}
```

Quero adicionar mais uma condição ai essa da erro:

```
    if ((nota >= 6) && (frequencia >= 75)) {
        alert("Aprovado");
    }
    else if (frequencia >= 50) {
        alert("Recuperação");
    }
    else {
        alert("Reprovado");
    }

    //essa
    else if (nota >= 4) {
        alert("Aluno de Recuperação");

    } else {
        alert("Aluno Reprovado");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sugiro que leia isso: [ask]

Comment: O `else` deve ser o último recurso quando todos os `else if` falharam, então ele deve ficar por último e só pode ter um.

Comment: Esse u´tlimo bloco de comparação que vc aponta dar erro, tem a ver com o primeiro ou são coisas separadas?

Comment: Colocando de forma simples: O `else {` é o último. Você não pode ter outro `else if` depois de um `else {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `else if` não pode ir depois do `else {`. O `else` deve ser a última condição, ela diz algo como, todas as outras são falsas, então deve executá-la. O correto seria entender a lógica primeiro.

Presumo que nota e frequência sejam importantes, mas só um `alert` poderá ser exibido por vez, tem bastante coisa estranha nas suas condições, mas creio que se frequência abaixo de 50 e nota abaixo 4 reprovam, então ambas podem dividir o mesmo `else`

Acaso o aluno precise ter frequência 50 ou nota 4 (não sendo necessárias ambas ao mesmo tempo), o correto então deve ser:

```
if (nota >= 6 && frequencia >= 75) {
    alert("Aprovado");
}
else if (frequencia >= 50) {
    alert("Recuperação");
}
else if (nota >= 4) {
    alert("Aluno de Recuperação");
} else {
    alert("Aluno Reprovado");
}
```

Mas acaso ambas sejam necessárias, no mínimo o aluno tenha frequência igual á ou maior que 50 e nota igual ou maior que 4, isto ao mesmo tempo, para estar de recuperação:

```
if (nota >= 6 && frequencia >= 75) {
    alert("Aprovado");
}
else if (frequencia >= 50 && nota >= 4) {
    alert("Aluno de Recuperação");
} else {
    alert("Aluno Reprovado");
}
```

Comment: O curioso é que se a frequencia for maior ou igual a 50 e a nota for 10, o aluno fica de recuperação... meio esquisita essa conta rs.. ou melhor, de a frequencia for 100 e a nota for 10, tb fica de recupa..

Comment: @dvd o autor não especificou a lógica necessária, e supondo que o sistema de ensino de escolas municipais, estaduais e particulares tem métodologias diferentes não cabe a mim questionar, podemos supor que aluno é nota 10, mas frequência reflete na qualificação dele (algo comum para determinar em universidades americanas, a presença é um fator de avaliação também).

Comment: Sim, a lógica dele que tá estranha.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, era praticamente o mesmo que você respondeu. Deletei aquela resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa obrigado pela edição o/

Comment: cara, eu tenho esse condigo em pascal apredendo agora coloque em javaScript pode dar uma olhada ele em pascall,,

Comment: @LuccasAndrade Se for ObjectPascal sim, crie uma nova pergunta para isto por favor.

Comment: Procedure ResultFin( NOTA, FREQUENCIA : real);
begin
readln(NOTA, FREQUENCIA);
if (NOTA >= 60) then begin
if (FREQUENCIA >= 75) then begin
writeln('APROVADO');
readln;
end
else if (FREQUENCIA > =50) then begin
writeln('RECUPERACAO');
readln;
end
else begin
writeln('REPROVADO');
readln;
end;
end
else if (NOTA >=40) then begin
writeln('RECUPERACAO');
readln;
end
else begin
writeln('REPROVADO');
readln;
end;
end.

Comment: ficou meio paia ai, to apredendo usar aqui esse forum

Comment: @LuccasAndrade não somos um fórum de debate, somos um site de perguntas e respostas diretas, ou seja sem rodeios e assistencialismo, clique aqui para fazer uma pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask sobre o assunto especifico de Pascal

Comment: irei criar agora @GuilhermeNascimento